# how to check multiple tables in spring security for authentication

Tags: java, database, spring, spring-security

I wrote the following code for spring security in applictionContext-Security.xml :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans:beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:beans="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/security
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/spring-security-3.0.xsd">

<global-method-security secured-annotations="enabled">
</global-method-security>

<!-- URL pattern based security -->


<http auto-config="true">
    <intercept-url pattern="/common/*" access="ROLE_ADMIN" />
     <form-login login-page="/login/login.jsp"/>
    <logout logout-success-url="/home/index.jsp"/>
</http>

<authentication-manager>
    <authentication-provider>

        <!-- <password-encoder hash="md5"/> <user-service> <user name="admin" 
            password="65dc70650690999922d7dcd99dbd4033" authorities="ROLE_ADMIN"/> </user-service> -->

        <jdbc-user-service data-source-ref="dataSource"
            authorities-by-username-query="
            select admin.userName as username, auth.authority as authority from Administrators admin, Authorities auth
            where admin.id=auth.AdministratorId and admin.userName= ?"
            users-by-username-query="select userName as username,hashedPassword as password, enabled as enabled
                                        from Administrators where userName= ?" />

    </authentication-provider>
</authentication-manager>

</beans:beans>
```

In that xml file, I can only check for administrator table from database for role.
How can I check for other table such as internal user, administrator and external user table to check for roles? Do I need to write query in new class instead of writing in xml. Please give me any idea or suggestion because I am just start doing it. Give me any link or site or code to view. thanks

Answer (score 7):

If you search for *authentication-provider* in the Spring Security [schema definition](http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/spring-security-3.0.xsd) you will see that it has an unbounded max occurrence. Consequently, you can add one `<authentication-provider>` for each table that you need to access inside your `</authentication-manager>`, e.g.

```
<authentication-manager>
    <authentication-provider>
        <jdbc-user-service data-source-ref="dataSource"
            authorities-by-username-query="select [...] from Administrators" 
        .../>
    </authentication-provider>

    <authentication-provider>
        <jdbc-user-service data-source-ref="dataSource"
            authorities-by-username-query="select [...] from Users" 
        .../>
    </authentication-provider>
</authentication-manager>
```